# PySide6 prevent repeating single line slot for multiple connections

Tags: connection, partial, slot, pyside6

I'm coming to you for some Pyside6 expertise:

I need a form to enter name, email, tel... of colleagues. I used a QFormLayout by adding 4 rows title-Qlineedit and 2 rows title-Qcombobox.

I want to get the values entered in the lineedit and combobox and put them into a dictionary **{'name': value1, 'email': value2...}**
I have to repeat the same connection for the 4 lineedit  to a slot which contains only one line but which changes according to the lineedit in question like this:

**lineedit_xxx.editionFinished(returnPressed).connect(methode1)**

**lineedit_yyy.editionFinished(returnPressed).connect(method2)**

I find this redundant and I tried with partial and lambda but without success:

with lambda I tried this form "**lambda lineedit_xxx.text(): dict['name'] = le_xxx.text()**" but it seems "illegal".

with partial I couldn't manage the change of lineedit (le_xxx, le_yyyy,...).

Is there a simple way to write only one method that captures all cases?

thank you all for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python enclosing scope variables with lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40997189/python-enclosing-scope-variables-with-lambda-function)

Comment: If that lambda is used in a loop, the lineEdit variable must be specified in its local scope: `lambda key=name, lineEdit=lineEdit: data.update({key: lineEdit.text()})`, but if you set object names to those widgets it can be easier.

Comment: Wonderful!! thank you musicamente!! I managed to do it with partial as well but requiring a slot